# How to remove characters in a string AFTER a given character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples that I want to remove the url extensions from. Here's what it looks like

```
['google.com', 'google.ru', 'google.ca']
```

Basically, I want to remove everything *after* the "**.**" in each one so that I'm returned with something like this

```
['google', 'google', 'google']
```

My instructions specifically tell me to use the `split()` function, but I'm confused with that as well. If it's also possible, I need to remove duplicates, so my final result would be:

```
['google']
```

Thanks for the help, sorry if my specifications are odd.

Comment: [split](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is linked here in the docs.

Comment: _I have a list of tuples_ Those aren't tuples.

Comment: I suggest that you start by simplifying the problem: given a single string, remove the top level domain and just print out the part before the dot. Can you figure out how to do that? Once you figure that out, make it a function that returns the part before the dot. Then figure out how to apply that function to each element of a list.

Comment: I'm sorry, my asignment used the words "list of tuples", not sure what it actually is. As long as its returned in that format.

Comment: I suspect that the words "list of tuples" was used in a specific context. However, those details are probably not important here. What you show here is a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `def` removes url extensions:

```
def removeurlextensions(L):
    L2 = []
    for x in range(len(L)):
        L2.append(L[x].split('.')[0])
    return L2
```

To print your list:

```
L = ['google.com', 'google.ru', 'google.ca']
print(removeurlextensions(L))
#prints ['google', 'google', 'google']
```

To remove duplicates you can use `list(set())`:

```
L = ['google.com', 'google.ru', 'google.ca']
print(list(set(removeurlextensions(L))))
#prints ['google']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `split`.

```
ls = ['google.com', 'google.ru', 'google.ca']
print([i.split('.', 1)[0] for i in ls])
# result = ['google', 'google', 'google']
```

And to remove the duplicate, you might want to use `set`.

```
mod = [i.split('.', 1)[0] for i in ls]
print(list(set(mod)))
# result = ['google']
```

Answer (score -1):

This will only work if all items are strings:

```py
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] = my_list[I].split('.')[0]
already_in_list = []
for item in my_list:
    if item in already_in_list:
        my_list.pop(item)
    else:
        already_in_list.append(item)
print(my_list)
```

I did do this from memory so if there is a bug please let me know.

Comment: Modifying the list you iterate over won't work the way you want. It would be better to build a new list of unique entries instead. Or better yet use `set()`.